# ImageView - ColorFilter

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, porter-duff, colorfilter

I have an ImageView and use a ColorFilter (PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY).

Is it possible to use this colorFilter but not on the whole image? It must be like a 'margin' / 'padding'.

Example:
The image width and height = 100dp. But the colorFilter must be 50dp (width and height) on the center of the ImageView.

The picture below is what I need (red = colorFilter)

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You will probably have to subclass `ImageView` and override the `onDraw` method.

Comment: @Lamorak Any suggestions how to make it work with overriding the onDraw, even with 2 ImageViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `ImageView` and override its `onDraw()` method. I am posting a minimalictic solution, modify to your needs!

```
public class OverlayImageView extends ImageView {
    Paint paint;
    float padding = 30;

    public OverlayImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public OverlayImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public OverlayImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(padding, padding, canvas.getWidth()-padding, canvas.getHeight()-padding, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. I did some changes so that the padding and the color can be set with a xml parameter.